# Changing LinkButton Content on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to change the a linkbutton content so when the mouse is over it, it will change it's content to "Sign Out".

the content before is:

```
   <asp:LinkButton  ID="Logged" runat="server" class="Connected"  OnClick="Logged_Click">Hello <asp:Label ID="name" runat="server" Text="name"></asp:Label></asp:LinkButton>
```

after:
suppose to be:

```
   <asp:LinkButton  ID="Logged" runat="server" class="Connected"  OnClick="Logged_Click">Log Out </asp:LinkButton>
```

i've uploaded my code to [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sagi151/vfq2L/111/) and it seems to be working but it doesn't show the label in the link button when not hovering.
also, it works on fiddle but not on my computer.

the way the `Login/basket` and `Register/Hello(#Logged)` works is that the user logs into the website and then the linkbuttons `"login"` and `"register"` dissapear and it shows the linkbuttons `"basket"` and "`hello + Label(contains User's FirstName)"`

on my computer,it doesn't change `hello(#Logged) LinkButton` to  `"Sign Out"`.

what can i do to fix it?

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.11.0 on local?

Answer (score 0):

I don;t know much about asp - but you can achieve this with CSS only

```css
#button:before{
  content:'Hello'}

#button:hover:before{
content:'Sign Out'}
```

```html
<button id="button" type="button"></button>
```

Comment: but i need to keep the label inside the LinkButton if you're done hovering

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
a.content::after{content:'Hello'}
a.content:hover::after{content:'Sign Out'}  
  
</style>
<a class="content"></a>
```

Comment: he he - @Farzin Kanzi - I just posted that solution :) - its a race in here with the answers

Comment: We write this in same time. See our times.

Comment: Yes it is, You won! :)

Comment: But your answer has a little problem: Asp:LinkButtons changes to link `<a>` in html file, not button.